# How to fix a JSONDecodeError?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am using Python to write CRUD operations (specifically create and read). I am writing a test script to create and read a dictionary to be later used in the mongoDB shell and have run into a JSONDecodeError.

I am new to python and JSON and have never run into this error before. How can I fix this error? Also, is there any way I can improve the code I am working on?

Thank you!

Here is my test script:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import CRUD
from CRUD import AnimalShelter
import random
import string
import json

shelter = AnimalShelter()

animal_id = 'A'.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))

print('animal_id %s being created' % animal_id)

outcome = json.loads(
    '{"": 78258, "age_upon_outcome": "1.6 years", "animal_id": "" + animal_id + "", "animal_type": "Dog", "breed": "Wolf Sheperd Mix", "color": "Grey", "date_of_birth": "2013-02-09", "datetime": "2014-04-11 13:26:00", "month_year": "2014-04-11T13:26:00", "name": "*JakeMo", "outcome_subtype": "Partner", "outcome_type": "Transfer", "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male", "Location_lat": "30.707721081886, "location:long": "-97.2735696278757", "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": 110.0799603174603}')

#print(outcome)

if shelter.create(outcome):
  print("animal added")

animal = shelter.read({"animal_id":animal_id})
print(animal)
```

And here is the error I get:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to actually show the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There is no way we can start to run your code and reproduce the error (which you didn't include, btw).

Comment: Provided Edit sorry

Comment: Please  always include code and error messages as text in the question itself, never as images - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also, the message clearly states that the JSON decoder was expecting a comma `,` somewhere, as the 61st character, and that it didn't find it. Check the string it tries to decode. We can't do that, as we can't reproduce the string in question. That's why a [mre] is needed...

Comment: Anyway, there's a problem in the way you try to create this string. Print it before trying to decode it. Have a look at `str.format` or f-strings.

Comment: Please also don't post pictures of text, post the text instead. That way, it can easily be found when someone has the same error. You did search for the error, right? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with these lines:

```py
outcome = json.loads(
    '{"": 78258, "age_upon_outcome": "1.6 years", "animal_id": "" + animal_id + "", "animal_type": "Dog", "breed": "Wolf Sheperd Mix", "color": "Grey", "date_of_birth": "2013-02-09", "datetime": "2014-04-11 13:26:00", "month_year": "2014-04-11T13:26:00", "name": "*JakeMo", "outcome_subtype": "Partner", "outcome_type": "Transfer", "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male", "Location_lat": "30.707721081886, "location:long": "-97.2735696278757", "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": 110.0799603174603}')
```

What you are doing here is creating a string and then using `json.loads` to parse it to a dict.  There's really no point in doing this when you can just create the dict directly:

```py
outcome = {
    "": 78258,
    "age_upon_outcome": "1.6 years",
    "animal_id": animal_id,
    "animal_type": "Dog",
    "breed": "Wolf Sheperd Mix",
    "color": "Grey",
    "date_of_birth": "2013-02-09",
    "datetime": "2014-04-11 13:26:00",
    "month_year": "2014-04-11T13:26:00",
    "name": "*JakeMo",
    "outcome_subtype": "Partner",
    "outcome_type": "Transfer",
    "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male",
    "Location_lat": "30.707721081886",
    "location:long": "-97.2735696278757",
    "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": 110.0799603174603
}
```

In theory you *could* have got the JSON parsing working by (a) changing the quotes around `animal_id` (note the differences in the highlighting of the `animal_id` variable in the code snippet below and at the top of my answer) and (b) fixing the missing double-quote after the value of the `Location_lat` property.  .  But as I've already explained that's not the best thing to do.

```py
outcome = json.loads(
    '{"": 78258, "age_upon_outcome": "1.6 years", "animal_id": "' + animal_id + '", "animal_type": "Dog", "breed": "Wolf Sheperd Mix", "color": "Grey", "date_of_birth": "2013-02-09", "datetime": "2014-04-11 13:26:00", "month_year": "2014-04-11T13:26:00", "name": "*JakeMo", "outcome_subtype": "Partner", "outcome_type": "Transfer", "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male", "Location_lat": "30.707721081886", "location:long": "-97.2735696278757", "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": 110.0799603174603}')
```